# How to extract slope value for a geometry point in GEE

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, vector, slope, extract

I want to extract slope values for various points in a certain region. Below is my current code which visualizes my region of interest on the map viewer

```
// dataset
var srtm = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');

// slope
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm);

// region of interest represented as a Geometry Rectangle
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([35.86, -16.64, 34.26, -15.21]);

// clip image dataset to roi
slope = slope.clip(roi)

var visualization_params = {min: 0, max: 60, palette:'white,red'};
Map.centerObject(roi);
Map.addLayer(slope, visualization_params, 'slope');
```

My goal is to derive the slope values for different coordinates within the rectangle, whereby i can map a point (e.g. 34.26, -15.91) to its slope value, then export the mappings.

I don't know how to go about it, and would need some help.

Comment: Did you try ploting charts first? https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/charts_image_regions

Comment: I appreciate the link, it pointed to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for something like this? Note that you can also make your own variable `points` using a feature collection of points you import or draw.

```
// make some random points
var points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(roi, 10);

// get the slope of the points
var slopes = slope.reduceRegions({
                    collection: points, 
                    reducer: ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(['slope']), 
                    scale: 250}); // define a scale in meters

// print and/or export
print('slope values', slopes)

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: slopes, 
  description: 'slopesExample', 
  fileFormat: 'CSV', 
});
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9c2ebc38f933f981903094a9f57d9b4d)

Comment: It works exactly how I wanted it to after importing a table of my points and making necessary adjustments, I appreciate. The issue now is that the x-point values in my table (comes in 2 decimal places) get approximated to higher decimal places which may affect the actual results a bit. Do you have an idea of how I can maintain the 2 decimal places the geometry points actually comes in?