# Extracting area of the clusters of specific coordinates

Tags: google-earth-engine, area, clustering, extract

I am working in GEE and I am trying to extract areas of clusters for some specific coordinates.

I have a clustered map of the area of all the clusters (using object-based clustering) and a list of coordinates. I am trying to extract areas of those clusters only whose coordinates are available. The coordinates can lie anywhere in the cluster but that cluster's whole area should be extracted.

I have tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358298/how-to-extract-slope-value-for-a-geometry-point-in-gee) approach but it isn't giving me the area of the whole cluster. What I am getting are the values like: 11.8, 8.7, etc. But the actual values are in 100's.

```
area_map = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6).addBands(clusters).reduceConnectedComponents(ee.Reducer.sum(), "clusters", 256) #Per-cluster area calculation
coordinates_features = ee.FeatureCollection(coordinates.tolist())
area_list = area_map.reduceRegions(collection= coordinates_features, reducer= ee.Reducer.first().setOutputs(['area']), scale=30)
print('area', area_list)
```

Can someone please guide, how do we achieve this?

Comment: Please, edit your question and put your own code. It is not clear which is the relation between the accepted answer with your question.

Comment: @xunilk I have added the code chunk now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do completely. It would have been helpful if you provided a complete, runnable script.

Here's my interpretation of what you're asking, correct me if I got this wrong. You have a cluster image, with a categorical image band, and a set of points. You want to find the area of the cluster each of these points fall on.

`reduceConnectedComponents()` have a max size, and when you make that value too large, you'll run out of memory. So you cannot find the complete area of a cluster with this approach.

Here's an idea:

- Find the clusters you're interested in by sampling the cluster image at your points
- Mask out the part of the cluster image with other cluster ids
- `reduceRegions()` on the pixel area and the masked cluster image, use a sum reducer grouped by the cluster id.

In principle, I suppose you could skip the first two steps too, you'd get the area for every cluster id. But if you have a lot of them, maybe it's better to skip them.

Here it is in JavaScript - it should be trivial to port to Python:

```
var clusterIds = clusters
  .sampleRegions({collection: points, scale: 10})
  .aggregate_array('cluster')
  .distinct()
var mask = ee.Image(ee.Array(clusterIds)).eq(clusters)
  .arrayReduce(ee.Reducer.max(), [0])
  .arrayFlatten([['cluster']])
var maskedClusters = clusters.updateMask(mask)
var areas = ee.List(
  ee.Image.pixelArea()
    .addBands(maskedClusters)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1), 
      geometry: region, 
      scale: 10,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
    .get('groups')
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/48cd99979238a57222b63def0351d9b2

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for the confusion, actually I am getting areas of the clusters (in km^2) but they are incorrect. I am using object-based clustering. The areas that I am getting are like: 11.8, 8.7, etc. But the actual areas of the clusters are in 100's. I ran your code but your code isn't giving me the areas (in numbers) at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I had made a mistake with the area calculation. I cannot help you more than this unless you providing more details..

Comment: Thank you for you help Daniel. I am using this repo by Noel Gorelick: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/gorelick/EE102 Could you please explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: the changes aren't getting saved in this repo. I added your code chunk to get the area. But I am getting this error: `List (Error)
Array: No numbers in 'values', must provide a type.
mask: Layer error: Array: No numbers in 'values', must provide a type.
maskedClusters: Layer error: Array: No numbers in 'values', must provide a type.` Here are the coordinates: [-121.7142,38.9714], [-121.8845,38.9735], [-121.8832,38.9297] and [-121.7211,38.9308]

Comment: sorry for bothering you. Could you please tell, how can we visualize  the "areas" it on map?

Comment: How would you want this to be visualized on a map?

Comment: I want to add a layer on the map. I asked a question regarding this too:  [Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461228/mapping-groups-data-on-the-map-using-map-addlayer-gee)