# Mapping groups' data on the map using Map.addLayer - GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, clustering, grouping

I wanted to extract the areas of specific clusters. I asked this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460675/extracting-area-of-the-clusters-of-specific-coordinates). I wanted to extract the areas of object-based clusters but the answer I got, resolved my issue. I need to visualize the clusters, `"areas"`. By visualize, I mean to visualize on the map using `Map.addLayer`.

Here is the code (that I got from the accepted answer):

```
var clusterIds = clusters
  .sampleRegions({collection: points, scale: 10})
  .aggregate_array('cluster')
  .distinct()
var mask = ee.Image(ee.Array(clusterIds)).eq(clusters)
  .arrayReduce(ee.Reducer.max(), [0])
  .arrayFlatten([['cluster']])
var maskedClusters = clusters.updateMask(mask)
var areas = ee.List(
  ee.Image.pixelArea()
    .addBands(maskedClusters)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1), 
      geometry: region, 
      scale: 10,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
    .get('groups')
)
```

I am getting this error, if I try to map the `areas` on the map by converting it to feature collection, `ee.FeatureCollection(areas)`:

```
EEException: Collection, argument 'features': Invalid type. 
Expected type: List<Element>. 
Actual type: List<Dictionary<Number>>.
```

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Comment: Do you want to show areas of each clusters as labels using the `Map.addLayer()`? Like this https://mitchellsql.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/image9.png

Comment: @Padmanabha I want to add it as a layer so that when I click anywhere on the cluster using inspector tool, it should give me the area of the whole cluster along with the generated group ID instead of the area of a single pixel. But the idea is somewhat the same as yours.